# "Hamlet was written by the William Shakespeare" or "Hamlet was written by William Shakespeare"

Tags: grammaticality, articles

I need some suggestion about the article in both these statement which one is grammatically correct ?

I was in school when my teacher teach me about articles.Its use with unique or big personality whether that was right or wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules governing English articles are convoluted, but generally speaking, the definite article *the* modifies a noun to distinguish a particular member of the set of things covered by the noun's definition. When a name uniquely identifies a person, the name already distinguishes the member in question, making the article superfluous. So you would say

> *Hamlet* was written by **{}** William Shakespeare.

where the empty braces indicate the position that an article might take.

But this isn't always the case. There must be thousands of men named Paul McCartney, so you could imagine the following introduction

> A (to B): I'd like you to meet Paul McCartney.
>   B (to Paul): Nice to meet you.
>   Paul (to B): Of course, I'm not **the** Paul McCartney.

Paul means he's not the world-famous musician. In fact, for some people, this isn't the case for William Shakespeare either. There are people who believe that William Shakespeare was a pseudonym for variously Edward de Vere, Sir Francis Bacon, or Christopher Marlowe among others. These disbelievers would say

> I don't believe that *Hamlet* was written by **the** William Shakespeare who was born in 1564 in Stratford-on-Avon. I believe that *Hamlet* was written by [*insert name of favorite hidden personage*].

The definite article is also used in the case when the name is used metaphorically. Shakespeare is almost universally recognized as one of the greatest dramatists of all time, so as an indicator of literary greatness, you might say of a modern author

> He is **the** William Shakespeare of his time.